# Can a subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ span $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Does the $\operatorname{span} \{(1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0)\}= \mathbb{R}^2?$ I was told the span of this set has dimension $2$ but what is the exact span?

Answer (score 4):

$\mathbf{R}^2$ is the set of all pairs of real numbers, so no, $\mathrm{Vect}(\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0)\})$ is not $\mathbf{R}^2$. It is, however, *isomorphic* to $\mathbf{R}^2$ (meaning that there exists a bijective linear map between the two).

Comment: Which basically means you replace $=$ with $\cong$ in your equation. The key is, all spans of two independent vectors in any real vector space are isomorphic to $\mathbb R^2$